# Selecting features on multiple layer used iface.actionSelectFreehand().trigger()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layers

I have two layers, "line" and "point", I need select a area whit freehand, in this area I need count the number of lines and number point.

I run the program and the result appears before selecting the area, I first need to select the area and then make the count that is within the area.

How can I perform this?

[image]

```
code
```

import qgis.core

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

class count quantities():

```
def __init__(self):

    layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
            continue
        layer.removeSelection()


    layer1="line"
    layer2="point"

    layer_name1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer1)[0]
    iface.setActiveLayer(layer_name1)
    layer11 = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()


    layer_name2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer2)[0]
    iface.setActiveLayer(layer_name2)
    layer22 = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

    iface.actionSelectFreehand().trigger()

    # Count numer lines
    n=0 
    selected_features = layer11.selectedFeatures()
    for i in selected_features:
        attrs = i.attributes()
        n=n+1

    j=0
    selected_features = layer22.selectedFeatures()
    for i in selected_features:
        attrs = i.attributes()
        j=j+1


    text="Number lines:" + str(n) +" Number Points:"+ str(j)

    QMessageBox.information(None, "Resume", texto)
```

then I need to add data within the attributes of each layer of the selected area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to select features from multiple layers at the same time with a single freehand drawing action, I think you will need to use a custom map tool class which inherits from `QgsMapTool` and overrides some of the available methods such as `canvasPressEvent` and `canvasMoveEvent`.

I have developed the script below, which you may test by pasting it into a blank editor in the Python console and clicking run. You can then use this code as model and adapt or extend it to modify your feature attributes.

Here is a gif which shows the custom map tool working:

[image]

Full script:

```py
class DrawFreehandPolygon(QgsMapTool):
    
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.polygon_rb = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
        self.set_points = []
        self.drawing_mode = False
        
        self.point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('point')[0]
        self.line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('line')[0]
        self.pt_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(self.point_layer.getFeatures())
        self.line_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(self.line_layer.getFeatures())
        
        self.msg_box = QMessageBox(iface.mainWindow())
        
        
    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        self.set_points.append(e.mapPoint())
        if self.drawing_mode == False:
            self.point_layer.removeSelection()
            self.line_layer.removeSelection()
            self.polygon_rb.reset()
            self.drawing_mode = True
        elif self.drawing_mode:
            self.polygon_rb.reset()
            pts_arr = [p for p in self.set_points]
            
            #Transform rubber band geometry to match point and polygon
            #layers (if their crs's are different)
            geom1, geom2 = self.transform_polygon(QgsProject.instance().crs(),
                            self.point_layer.crs(),
                            self.line_layer.crs(),
                            QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([pts_arr]),
                            QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([pts_arr]))
            
            point_candidates = self.pt_idx.intersects(geom1.boundingBox())
            for f in self.point_layer.getFeatures(point_candidates):
                if f.geometry().within(geom1):
                    self.point_layer.selectByIds([f.id()], QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)
                    ######
                    #...Do something here with feature attributes or store them
                    # in a list and modify them later. E.g. you could have a method
                    # which is called when the message box is accepted.
                    ######
            line_candidates = self.line_idx.intersects(geom2.boundingBox())
            for f in self.line_layer.getFeatures(line_candidates):
                if f.geometry().intersects(geom2):
                    self.line_layer.selectByIds([f.id()], QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)
                    ######
                    #...Do something here with feature attributes or store them
                    # in a list and modify them later. E.g. you could have a method
                    # which is called when the message box is accepted.
                    ######
            self.drawing_mode = False
            self.set_points.clear()
            self.msg_box.setText('Number of Lines: {}\nNumber of Points: {}'.format(
                self.line_layer.selectedFeatureCount(),
                self.point_layer.selectedFeatureCount()))
            self.msg_box.setGeometry(500, 300, 350, 200)
            self.msg_box.show()
    
    def transform_polygon(self, canvas_crs, l1_crs, l2_crs, g1, g2):
        if canvas_crs != l1_crs:
            xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(canvas_crs, l1_crs, QgsProject.instance())
            g1.transform(xform)
        if canvas_crs != l2_crs:
            xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(canvas_crs, l2_crs, QgsProject.instance())
            g2.transform(xform)
        return g1, g2
        
        
    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.drawing_mode:
            self.polygon_rb.reset()
            self.set_points.append(e.mapPoint())
            if len(self.set_points) > 2:
                pts_arr = [p for p in self.set_points]
                self.polygon_rb.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([pts_arr]))
                self.polygon_rb.setStrokeColor(QColor(240, 165, 105))
                self.polygon_rb.setFillColor(QColor(240, 165, 105, 85))
                self.polygon_rb.setWidth(1)
                self.polygon_rb.show()

    def deactivate(self):
        self.polygon_rb.reset()
        self.point_layer.removeSelection()
        self.line_layer.removeSelection()


mt = DrawFreehandPolygon(iface.mapCanvas())
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(mt)
```

Comment: Excellent, worked very well